# Why am I getting : "mutating method sent to immutable object" when trying remove from MutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I can't figure out why I am getting the 'mutating method sent to immutable object' in this piece of code. The array must be immutable somehow but I don't know why.

Interface:

```
    @interface SectionsViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate> {

    UITableView *table;
    UISearchBar *search;
    NSMutableDictionary *names;
    NSMutableArray *keys;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *table;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISearchBar *search;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *allNames;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *names;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *keys;

-(void) resetSearch;
-(void) handleSearchForTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm;

@end
```

Notice that names is a MutableDictionary.

The following line is throwing the exception

```
[array removeObjectsInArray:toRemove];
```

Here the method in full context:

```
-(void)handleSearchForTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm
{
    NSMutableArray *sectionsToRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(NSString *key in self.keys)
    {
        NSMutableArray *array = [names valueForKey:key];
        NSMutableArray *toRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for(NSString *name in array)
        {
            if([name rangeOfString:searchTerm
                           options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == NSNotFound)
                [toRemove addObject:name];
        }
        if([array count] == [toRemove count])
            [sectionsToRemove addObject:key];

        [array removeObjectsInArray:toRemove];
        [toRemove release];
    }
    [self.keys removeObjectsInArray:sectionsToRemove];
    [sectionsToRemove release];
    [table reloadData];
}
```

I am assigning array from the result of this [names valueForKey:key];
array is of type 'MutableArray' What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`valueForKey:` returns an `NSArray`. It doesn't matter that you are sending it to an `NSMutableArray`.

You could either cast the result to `(NSMutableArray *)`, but my personal preference is to get a copy:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[[names valueForKey:key] mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

Comment: Remember that you need to either `autorelease` or `release` the result of `mutableCopy`;  I edited for the `autorelease` pattern for expediency.

Comment: names is an NSMutableDictionary. If that key's value is set as a mutable array, it will return a mutable array. What you're saying would only apply if it was an 'ordered to-many' relationship accessed via KVC (in which case mutableArrayValueForKey: would be the way to go). And anyway, casting the pointer returned (even if necessary to avoid compiler warnings, which it isn't as valueForKey returns id) wouldn't affect the runtime behaviour of the object it references.

Comment: `valueForKey:` won't *necessarily* return an immutable object in any case; when sent to a dictionary, such as `names`, it will return the object that you originally put in the dictionary, regardless of the mutability of the dictionary. Putting an immutable array into a mutable dictionary means you will get the same immutable array from it.

Answer (score 3):

The variable is statically typed as an `NSMutableArray`, but it would appear that the object assigned to the variable is not an `NSMutableArray`. The type of the variable is just a hint for the compiler to use when type checking and choosing method signatures — you still have to take some care to make sure you're actually assigning the type that the variable says it should hold.