# NSMutableArray removeAllObjects results in a crash

Tags: ios, exception, ios6, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` in my `ViewController` which is the datasource for my `UITableView` defined like so:

```
NSMutableArray *messageArray;
```

I have a method to reload the tableView data, before which, I want to clear the existing table data.

If I use the following code:

```
  [messageArray removeAllObjects];    
  [self.tableView reloadData];
```

I get the following exception:

> 2013-02-12 14:20:30.378 appname[20998:907] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to
>   immutable object'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x3939e3e7 0x35dd6963 0x3939e307 0x393200e7 0x392eb5e5 0x7cda3 0x3a236047 0x3a2360d1 0x3a236047
>   0x3a235ffb 0x3a235fd5 0x3a23588b 0x3a235d79 0x3a15e5c9 0x3a14b8b1
>   0x3a14b1bf 0x336305f7 0x33630227 0x393733e7 0x3937338b 0x3937220f
>   0x392e523d 0x392e50c9 0x3362f33b 0x3a19f291 0x79c11 0x39be4b20)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

But if I use the following code, it works.

```
  NSMutableArray *emptyArray = [NSMutableArray new];
  messageArray = emptyArray;    
  [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Why am I getting an error for `removeAllObjects`?
Could this be the culprit?

```
    NSMutableDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    messageArray = responseDictionary[@"data"];
```

Comment: Is this related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707360/why-am-i-getting-mutating-method-sent-to-immutable-object-when-trying-remove

Comment: Where do you alloc messageArray? Where do you fill it (ie what objects are in it when you removeAllObjects)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Could this be the culprit?
>
> ```
> NSMutableDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
> messageArray = responseDictionary[@"data"];
> ```

Yes, you want to use the option for mutable containers:

```
NSMutableDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:NULL];
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your "NSMutableArray" is actually an NSArray cast to NSMutableArray.

Search your code for something like this:

```
messageArray = (NSMutableArray *)[obj methodReturningNSArray];
```

`removeAllObjects` will only work on a true NSMutableArray, as the error "mutating method sent to immutable object" states.

Comment: I don't have anything like that but I do think it's somehow being cast to NSArray

Comment: By default, JSON creates NSArray's not NSMutableArrays's, so your guess is correct.  Using mutableCopy on the array as tkanzakic shows is one solution, i.e. messageArray = [responseDictionary[@"data"] mutableCopy];

Answer (score 1):

you has to change this line:

```
messageArray = responseDictionary[@"data"];
```

to:

```
messageArray = [responseDictionary[@"data"] mutableCopy];
```

by default the objects that you get from a dictionary are non-mutables

Comment: No, objects you get from a dictionary are the objects you put into it before. In case of deserialization that depends on the desirialization code. `NSPropertyListSerialization` for example supports both.

Comment: yes, you're are right, I really mean from `NSJSONSerialization`, unless you specify that you are interest in mutable copies

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry for sounding snappy.

Answer (score 0):

The `messageArray` returned by your data reload is not an `NSMutableArray`, but is instead an `NSArray`. If you place a debugger stop after the reload you can verify this. Use `.mutableCopy` when setting `messageArray`.

Answer (score 0):

How to find the spot with the error:

1. Check if you @synthesize a property named `messageArray`. If this property is of `NSArray` type or declared with the `copy` modifier the synthesized setter is the culprit.
2. If not, redeclare the ivar `NSMutableArray *const messageArray`. Now the compiler will show you each assignment. Check for NSArray assigments. Don't forget to revert the declaration after that.
3. When done, rename the ivar to `_messageArray` to find direct accesses faster in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you have set `NSMutableArray` to an instance of `NSArray`, not `NSMutableArray` or you declared `NSMutableArray` as a property of type `NSArray vs. NSMutableArray`.

`Cocoa` documentation uses the word `immutable` to *refer to read-only*, **can't-be-changed-after-initialization objects**.

Also, you should follow `Cocoa / Objective-C` naming conventions. Namely, class names start with upper case; variables take the form myArray (*or something more descriptive, preferably*).

You can find more detail of the [copyWithZone reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and in the [NSMutableCopying protocol reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSMutableCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).